# xcolor error when using Colourbrewer

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have the following code, that draws an array and fills it with various colors. The code works perfectly when I use general colors such as red, blue, green, etc.. But when I use `colorbrewer` library it gives the following error.

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Dark2-3-2'.
! Package pgf Error: Unsupported color model `='. Sorry.
```

The snippet is as follows

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,matrix,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{colorbrewer}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=0pt,
start chain = A going right,
X/.style = {rectangle, draw,% styles of nodes in string (chain)
            minimum width=1.5ex, minimum height=2.5ex,
            outer sep=0pt, on chain}, % by default braces are mirrored
]
\node[X, fill= Dark2-3-2] {};
\node[X,fill=red] {};  
\node[X,fill=blue  ] {};
\node[X, fill=green] {};
\node[X,fill=yellow] {};  
\node[X,fill=yellow  ] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your use of `Dark2-3-2` probably stems from [this](http://www.traag.net/2014/06/05/281/), which requires [a different version of the `colorbrewer` tikz library](https://github.com/vtraag/tikz-colorbrewer/blob/master/tikzlibrarycolorbrewer.code.tex).

Comment: @Werner Aaah. Yes, that is exactly where I saw it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're after `Dark2-B` I think, not `Dark2-3-2`.

If you look at the array of colours in the `Dark2` scheme from the `pgfplots` manual,

[image: Dark2 scheme from manual]

note that there is one colour per column. To get a `cycle list`, you use for example `Dark2-5`, to get a list of five colours, but to get a specific colour you use `Dark2-<letter>`, where the letter indicates the column.